# type of an array of object whose key is in template Literal Types

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get the following type: `[{a: string}, {b: string}]` by using the `type k = 'a' | 'b'`.

What I have tried is to use the following which adds all the keys to the object type as optional

```
let x: Array<{[key in k]?: string}>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
type Union = 'a' | 'b'

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

// credits https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true;

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

// Converts union to overloaded function
type UnionToOvlds<U> = UnionToIntersection<
  U extends any ? (f: U) => void : never
>;

type PopUnion<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends (a: infer A) => void ? A : never;

// credits https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901
type UnionToArray<T extends string, A extends unknown[] = []> =
  IsUnion<T> extends true
  ? PopUnion<T> extends string
  ? UnionToArray<Exclude<T, PopUnion<T>>, [Record<PopUnion<T>, string>, ...A]>
  : never
  : [Record<T, string>, ...A];

type Result = UnionToArray<Union>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZygXigcgIaagHywCNMAoUgegqgGMAnCAEwWAGcoBzJCd4JKABbBgYVgC4qrYNhoBrJADcIdAGYAbJAHcAdDSQBbCtgoBWAAwBmAOwmATAA4AbKVCRYiFABUkASTjBlVggaYGQ4AB4YAD50KAAKGCgIAA8AuEZ2bDgQKAB%20eNkxWABKdBiFJARGKCK4CCU6UpS0jPjSKChCqAQ4FWUoH1JStHLKxna8gYna%20uUAbnIqWgZmNkFhUQkKKRl5BvUtXQMKAFcgulYKAEZbEysLABYKUNCsgFoaZUQ9BWw3xjo2C4%20gQdBc4GgPlY8DC4U8MQwAG1PABdJKpCDpdiImFeXz%20QLBUIoOFRNH5FTYNRBGpQYB0E4QBbgtwANSpjNYpNinkRsggICQKigqMW1AAwigGmsTh5UHwoIplBpsIwmFAVLKQmEWdBcXBvAB5BRqDKRBHuMLePwBC5E2ETRLNTGtLI5fJxFRFGDDUZVWl1BqkKLM1zQAAKSDA%20vNsX1RpNZui6Ja7Di2CKPT6dCgAEFfVAKv78rmA7M6MylvQmCx2EIROIqBwWAITkQjoYQfQkKwhcAKJ4IQBlegIMD9hCsVic64WWwATnsAGJJ9PggZ9JjgG8Ho57Fcrg952YrrrLXjc3RASA4SmXewpHQehwADR5u9YqCy2RwLRwRFokiKIIhMUIxvCH6tPSjITPkkbRnK3LOp%20j7PrB54Gkgl7XuEACiyQ0GoJxqnCb7weBURRG%20iIAErrnQjDhORiHwm%20qFwBwVFQNoPG5sB0xQIGygCbR9GMZ4bH0s%20XE8dofGhhCUB0dOajAHGcreNh2A3vqURAA)

[Blog](https://catchts.com/union-array)

More explanation you will find in links above each type util

If you are interested in more operations over literal types [this](https://catchts.com/tuples) article will help you

Comment: Okay that's not a trivial thing !

Comment: it is definitely not, at least for me. Maybe smbd will come up with smth more easier